# PyCharm "permission denied" on creating Anaconda environment

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, conda

When I create a Conda environment, I have given PyCharm root permissions, but it still appears

> "permission denied".

The first I succeeded. Then I failed again and again.

[image]

Comment: Please: do not include images (and if you need them, include them inline, not as link). It is much better if you copy the text in the answer: easy for us to see it, and to copy on answer. [I'll not open random link from random people: this is a good rule, and programmers are a target]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to give your interpretter root permissions. There is a tutorial https://esmithy.net/2015/05/05/rundebug-as-root-in-pycharm/ on how to do this